# Get Directory Name from FileInfo object

Tags: powershell

I was looking for a executable location and I use the following command:

```powershell
PS C:\> dir -recurse -filter "notepad++.exe" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | select -first 1 -Property Directory
```

And it returns:

```powershell
Directory
---------
C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSource\Notepad++
```

How can I get the string "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSource\Notepad++"?
I have try a lot of different commands but none of them work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I will aproach this step by step, a single line solution is presented at the end of the first part of my answer.*

---

**The Specific Solution for Your Case**

Right now, you are receiving an object. One simple solution is to store the object in a variable and access the path of the directory as a string, by using the `ToString()` method.

```powershell
$a = dir -recurse -filter "notepad++.exe" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | select -first 1 -Property Directory
$a.Directory.ToString()
```

In that case, you can also shorten your `dir` call like in the following snippet.

```powershell
$a = dir -recurse -filter "notepad++.exe" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | select -first 1
$a.Directory.ToString()
```

Or use the DirectoryName property, like in Bacon Bits answer.

```powershell
$a = dir -recurse -filter "notepad++.exe" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | select -first 1
$a.DirectoryName
```

And finally, you can do it in a single line, too.

```powershell
dir -recurse -filter "notepad++.exe" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | select -first 1 | % { $_.Directory.ToString() }
```

Or, again, use the DirectoryName Property.

```powershell
dir -recurse -filter "notepad++.exe" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | select -first 1 | % { $_.DirectoryName }
```

---

All of the solutions above will return the path as string, on your system that would be the following one.

```powershell
C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSource\Notepad++
```

---

**The General Approach to the Solution**

If you want to access any property of an object in PowerShell, you need to know the available properties first. Just pipe your object to the `Get-Member` Cmdlet and PowerShell will print you the TypeName and a table of property names, types and definitions.

```powershell
dir -recurse -filter "notepad++.exe" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | select -first 1 | Get-Member
```

A quick web research would deliver even more information about the type of your object.

When you know which property you want to use, you may access it by using one of the following methods.

1. Store the returned object (e.g. as `a`) and access the property by using `$a.PropertyName`
2. Pipe the object to `% { $_.PropertyName }`
3. Use `-ExpandProperty PropertyName`, like Bacon Bits did.

Just use the style that fitrs best to your remaining code.

---

**Difference Between `-Property` and `-ExpandProperty`**

`-Property` will provide you with an object, containing exactly this property.

`-ExpandProperty` will return the property itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-ExpandProperty` parameter of `Select-Object`, and ask for the `DirectoryName` property instead of the `Directory` property:

```
dir -recurse -filter "notepad++.exe" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | select -first 1 -ExpandProperty DirectoryName
```